# Как менять размер шрифта TextView в процессе чтения текста?

Tags: java, android, android-textview

Как при нажатии на кнопку программно изменить весь размер текста?
например в dimens прописала два варианта, 25 и 50. 
Или в процентном соотношении менять. От 0 до 100 %

Answer (score 2):

Используя метод [setTextSize(int unit, float size)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(int,%20float)) или [setTextSize(float size)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(float)).

Comment: обращаюсь к размерам через ресурсы, но не работает. 

public void onClickPlus(View view) {
        TextView btn_plus = new TextView(this);
        btn_plus.setTextSize(R.dimen.font_plus);



    }

    public void onClickMinus(View view) {
        TextView btn_minus = new TextView(this);
        btn_minus.setTextSize(R.dimen.font_minus);
    }
}

Comment: @TatevikAzatyan А что у вас должно было заработать? судя по вашему примеру, вы просто создаете новый экземпляр текствью и у него выставляете размер текста.

Comment: Такс. У меня в папке ресурсов есть xml файлы (мои созданные книжки). Мне нужно, чтобы размер текста в этих файлах менялся при нажатии на кнопку. А что тогда нужно создавать ? Я просто новичок в этом деле. Не судите. Мне, как я поняла, не нужно создавать новый экземпляр тествью.